# What is the reason for this many errors in my former MATLAB, now Python code?

Tags: python, matlab, language-translation

I am currently translating this piece of MATLAB code to Python code. The code is about calculating fractal dimension of images by turning it to a binary array and using box counting method.

But errors such as "found bad_character", "end of statement expected" happen all at once in some part of the code.

```python
import numpy as np
import math as mt
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot
I = cv2.imread()#plase image location

h, w, c = I.cv2.shape

#print('width:  ', w)
#print('height: ', h)
#print('channel:', c)

largerLength = np.maximum(h, w)

power = np.ceil(mt.log2(largerLength))
lengthNum =2**power
grayIm = cv2.cvtColor(I, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, binaryIm = cv2.threshold(grayIm,125,256,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

#get the amount of padding to add
padRow = lengthNum - I.shape
padCol = lengthNum − I.shape
#pad I with 0’s after its last row and column
I = np.padarray(I , [padRow , padCol], ’post’) #??

boxCountstore = np.zeros(1 , power) #??
#boxcountstore = zeros(1, power)
scalestore = np.zeros(1 , power) #??
#scalestore = zeros(1, power)
boxNum = 1

#use the for loop to shrink the box size
for i in range(1, power):
    boxCount=0
    for boxrow in range(1,2**i):#i was i-1
        for boxcol in range(1,2**i):
                #thefourtermsbelowaretheindexrange
                #ofthecurrentboxwearechecking
            var1 = lengthNum/boxNum
            var2 = boxrow-1
            minRow = 1 + var1∗var2
            minCol = 1 + var1∗var2
            maxRow = var1∗boxrow
            maxCol = var1∗boxcol
            contain=0
            for row in range(minRow,maxRow):
                for col in range(minCol,maxCol):
                    if I(row,col): ###????
                    #ifture,thenthecurrentbox
                    #containstheobject
                        boxCount=boxCount+1
                        contain=1
                        break #breakfromthe”col”
                if contain:
                    break #breakfromthe”row”loop



scale=1/(lengthNum/boxNum)
boxNum =  2*boxNum #doublethenumberofboxes
#per dimension

#fit a line for the log − log plot in the least square
#sense


FD = np.polyfit(np.log(scalestore),np.log(boxCountstore),1)

#returntheslope
#FD=FD(1)


# (225, 400, 3)
# <class 'tuple'>
```

[original code, matlab_pt1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyH5H.png)
[original code, matlab_pt2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tGQx.png)

I couldn't figure what is wrong with the part that I use the variables `var1` and `var2`.
Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: If you are seeing errors, please [edit] to include the _full_ error traceback, as that contains valuable information like the line that is causing the error and the actual error message. Without this detail it's hard to know how to help, since we can't run your code without knowing your input and expected output (see: [mcve])

Comment: You copy-pasted code form some fancy formatted document. This document is full of characters that are illegal in Python code (and would be illegal in MATLAB too!). For example I see a `’` quote, which should be a `'` character instead. Don't copy-paste fancy formatted code into your program, type it in.

Comment: Also, don't you notice the weird offset of `∗` compared to `*`? These are the sort of character translations you get when you typeset code in LaTeX.